# How to find x,y coordinate from an image?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, image-processing

I want to finding x,y coordinate of a white dot in a black cycle, and store the x,y coordinate in the variable array.

[image: *Example Image*]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878325/what-are-the-possible-fast-ways-to-detect-circle-in-an-image here is a place to start, even though it doesn't describe the principles in C# you might still get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can convolute your image with a kernel that resembles that white dot with the black circle.  local maxima in the output will give you the object positions.