# Getting locations of objects inside a picture

Tags: ios, camera

So here is a question that is sure to stump some people.

Here is my scenario. I want a user to take a picture of something, in this case it will be just a black rectangle with white circles on it. I don't care about the size of the circles, but I want to know how many circles there are and where they are located in respect to the photo. Then a user will enter the width and height of the photo they just took and I will be able to tell the distance the circles are from each other.

Does anyone have any clue how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will get a straight forward answer.But below is my approach.

- Take the image, get its pixel data using CGBitmapContext ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)).
- Now search in the array, where white pixels are located (white pixels - colorvalue >240/255).
- Now try to find its white-circle-centre using some algorithm ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878325/what-are-the-possible-fast-ways-to-detect-circle-in-an-image)).
- Store those centers in an array,and later when user gives width ,return widths relatively.